# script / class to parse stackoverflow-like markup

Tags: php, markup, wiki-markup

I'm looking for a script that parses markup like the one used in wikis and in stackoverflow...

I prefer something that I can easily customize for additional markup

I'm using PHP, and I'm looking for a standalone class that requires no external dependencies from some framework, lib, etc.

I'm talking about a class/script that converts this:

```
**bold** 
- aaa
- bbb
- ccc
```

into:

**bold**

- aaa
- bbb
- ccc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The specific markup language used by StackOverflow is called Markdown. A Google search for `PHP Markdown` turns up several libraries; I haven't used any of them so I can't recommend one.

Comment: PHP Markdown looks unnecessarily difficult (1500+ rows of code)... i'm looking for something smaller! thanks

Comment: @toPeerOrNotToPeer: So, do you want Markdown, or just something Markdown-like?  You might want to clarify your question so that you can get better answers.

Comment: something simpler! I've looked at markdown and textile but they are both too complex. and, i want to customize the syntax, if possible, and limit features, if there are something that i don't want to use!